# How to add assets to Adobe's CQ5 from PHP

Tags: php, rest, adobe, aem

I am trying to add content to Adobe's CQ5 DAM with the REST APIs from PHP.  Wondering if there are any examples of this, because I am struggling to figure it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third-party API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following function will upload an image using PUT method, which is enough to add new asset to DAM.

```
function uploadFile($url, $login, $password, $filePath) {
        $name = basename($filePath);
        $fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url/$name");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePath));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

        return $result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
uploadFile('http://localhost:4502/content/dam/geometrixx',
    'admin',
    'admin',
    'my-picture.jpg');
```

it will create new DAM asset under `/content/dam/geometrixx/my-picture.jpg`.

Comment: that worked great on the local server, but when I try to do it to the cloud server I get a 409 Conflict error.  There are no other files in that folder on the server.

Comment: Turns out it was because I was not uploading to author-sitename.adobeaemcloud.com